# Is it possible to measure DOM render time when replacing all children of a node?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way measure the time it takes for a browser to re-render a section of a page?

I'm moving away from a js library which I used to render tables which now has become a bottleneck on the page I'm working on. So I'm switching to sweet VanillaJS.

I have a table with 10.000 rows (for the test) and 4 - 8 columns. Each column is sortable. What I'm trying to determine is which way is the quickest to sort this table and I'm trying three approaches.

1. Take the array of rows from the DOM and sort them depending of a cell. Then reinsert all the rows.
2. Sort the javascript array, delete all rows and recreate and insert all rows.
3. Sort the javascript array, generate an HTML String with all rows and replace the parents innerHTML.

If I time these three ways in javascript it doesn't take into account the rendering of the DOM once I update the sorting. The third option tends to be the fastest, but not by much over the second option.

The problem is that the timer stops when all the javascript is finished (obviously), but the DOM hasn't finished rendering so my tests aren't that accurate.

Is there a way to measure a re-render of parts of the DOM? If not, does anyone know which option of sorting a huge table is the most performant way?

Comment: I would think this would be system-dependent.  Therefore, you would need to specify a system, and do relative comparisons only.

Comment: Seems to me that 10,000 of anything is too much to show on a single page.

Comment: @Pointy i know, but its for the test to see which way performs better.

Comment: assuming a static  error (dt between last finish and actual stop), i guess u can use `requestAnimationFrame` and poll for state

Comment: You might have luck using f12 and meassuring the loading and scripting times

Comment: You are displaying 10000 rows all at once or is it paged? Really deletion of rows is not an issue, issue would be adding them back. Heck just rendering 10K rows without building it will be slow in a browser.

Comment: @epascarello for this test and the real page its not paged. In the actual page the rows can vary from 10 - 500 rows, I can't page them as the customer wont allow it. And there is a lot of other rendering going on, on the page at the same time, so the sorting which currently slows everything down needs to be very fast.

Comment: Then you are pretty much going to have crappy performance. The bottle neck is rendering rows. There are tweaks you can do, but in the end the bottle neck is the browser rendering it. Fastest way to delete is going to be a good ole innerHTML = ''. How to improve rendering, hard to tell since we have no idea what you are doing.

Comment: @epascarello I know, but in comparison to knockout which I'm now removing vanillajs is 2 - 3 times faster with the sorting.

Comment: You are sorting actually DOM? Reading and parsing cells to sort? Have you tried datatables or any other script that has been out there for ages?

Comment: @epascarello in what sense? In option 1 I am testing it, its quicker than knockout but slower than the other two options. Do you have another suggestion that could be more performant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Estradiaz you could use requestAnimationFrame() to measure the time it takes to render the DOM. Know that this isn't a perfect solution and might not give an accurate enough time, but in my case its sufficient enough.

```
startMeasure() {
    let start = null
    let previous = 0
    let threshold = 400
    const step = (timestamp) => {
        if (!start) start = timestamp;

        if (this.stopped && previous !== 0 && timestamp - previous > threshold) {
            console.log(`Total time: ${timestamp - start}ms`)
            return
        }

        previous = timestamp;
        window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
    }
    window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
}
```

As Browsers try to render pages at around 60 FPS which is about 16.6ms per frame we can assume that frames taking longer than that could be the rendering of the DOM. The next frame should therefor be the one where the DOM finished rendering. I call the function above like this:

```
function sortRows(th) {
    this.stopped = false;
    this.startTimer()

    // Calculations and DOM updates here. 

    this.stopped = true;
}
```

I added the `this.stopped` variable to not let the calculations trigger the end of the measure in case the slow down the rendering.

In the case of sorting and re-rendering of 10.000 rows the sorting and recreation of the rows took around 350ms and you could visibly see that the rendering took a little bit longer, so I put the `threshold` to 400. When trying 1000 rows sorting and creation took about 35ms and I put the `threshold` to 40.

And last if anyone is curious, the results of sorting and redrawing of a huge table. Tested on a MacBook Pro 2015 13" Base model.

```
                10.000rows
Knockout        2350 - 2900ms
Option 1        1800 - 2200ms
Option 2        1350 - 1600ms
Option 3         900 - 1250ms
```